# how to set asp.net identity connection string from dll file not from webconfig?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dll, asp.net-identity

I`m working for a company that they use dll for connection string and i`m tryng to change asp.net identity default connection string in ApplicationDbContext class ,
my connection class that use dll is like this :

```
public class HRConnection
{       
    public string HR_con
    {
        get
        {
            return "server=192.168.1.21; database=HR; user=teamuser ; password=t123@456  ; connection timeout=30";                
        }
    }
}
```

i`ve tried to pass string like this , but it didn`t work

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    string  HrConn = new HRConnection().HR_con;
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base(HrConn, throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
}
```

how do i set the connection in code and not from webconfig file ?

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem like this

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base(new HRConnection().HR_con, throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First try passing the hard coded string as first parameter in call to base. If that works then I would suggest defining your string like this:

```
public class HRConnection
{       
    public readonly static string HR_con = "server=192.168.1.21; database=HR; user=teamuser ; password=t123@456  ; connection timeout=30";
}
```

and use like this:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base(HRConnection.HR_con, throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Might as well put your connectionstring hardcoded in the base constructor parameters, no point defining an extra class for it imo

Comment: @AlexanderDerck I agree with your opinion. It is just that in case the connection string is to be used in other parts of the code too.

Comment: it`s not quit like this , the hard coded string is for test and the actual connection return string from dll so that developers like me can`t access.

Comment: @MTaher Was my suggestion of any help? Did it work for you?

Comment: @sachin , thanks man , but i`ve already found the answer and wrote it here before yours.